# system.runAs gives different result after querying

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, query, runas

My class is using `with sharing` keyword and method has a query on object which system admin only has access.

```
List<Login__c> recList = [select id, clientId__c, clientsecret__c from login__c];
```

So in my test class to test for multiple profiles I am using below:

```
User u = [select id from user where profile.name != 'System Administrator' Limit 1];
system.runAs(u) {
    MainClass.retrieveQuery();
}
```

I expect above to throw error when method is called as query in that method can only be run succesfully by system admin but it doesnot throw any error.

However, if I pass specific profile name which is not system admin as below, it runs as expected throws an exception "List has no rows for assignment to sObject"

```
User u = [select id from user where profile.name = 'Integration User' Limit 1];
system.runAs(u) {
    MainClass.retrieveQuery();
}
```

My another question is how to catch list has no exceptions error. I tried below:

```
List<Login__c> recList = new List<Login__c>();
try {
    recList = [select id, clientId__c, clientsecret__c from login__c];
} catch(QueryException qe) {
    system.debug('Query exception: '+qe);
} catch(Exception e) {
    system.debug('Exception: '+e);
}
```

Even though above code throws exception "List has no rows exception" when run by non-system admin profile, this exception is not caught in either catch block.

Comment: (1) always a good idea to select a user that has `IsActive = true`; (2)`recList = [select id, clientId__c, clientsecret__c from login__c];` will never throw query has no rows exception; it will return 0 rows

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000159853&type=1 . Also , use a list and always check if it empty or not before doing something with it.

Comment: Your query - `[select id from user where profile.name = 'Integration User' Limit 1];` does not return any user so the exception where as `select id from user where profile.name != 'System Administrator' Limit 1` returns a value so no exception. Nothing to do with `system.runAs` or `with sharing` keyword here.

Comment: Thanks sfdcbat and cropredy.. thats the exact issue here, my org has no active non-system admin users..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only get an error that `List has no rows for assignment to SObject` if you assign to a single record:

```
static testmethod void demonstration()
{
    QueryException expectedException;

    Test.startTest();
        try
        {
            User record = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = null];
        }
        catch (QueryException q)
        {
            expectedException = q;
        }
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertNotEquals(null, expectedException, 'An exception should be thrown');
}
```

You are assigning to a list, so an empty query result is not an exception case. Whether you use `system.runAs` or not has nothing to do with the behavior difference you observe here.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. What about the system.runAs not throwing any exception when querying as non-system-admin profile ?

Comment: It won't throw an exception because you are assigning to a list...You're comparing two different changes and blaming the wrong one for the difference in observed behavior.